# Почему выводится только последний элемент массива

Tags: android, kotlin

Фильтрую массив по параметрам ID которые приходят из другого массива.
Не могу понять, почему выводится только последний элемент

```
var filteredCats : MutableList<CarsItemDataBase> = ArrayList()

statHereItemList.forEach {

    val f:Int = it.car

    filteredCats = catsItemList.filter { 
        it.id == f 
    } as MutableList<CarsItemDataBase>
}

textTotalCats.setOnClickListener {
    mainAdapter.setData(filteredCats)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// filteredCats = catsItemList.filter { it.id == f } as MutableList<CarsItemDataBase>
filteredCats.addAll(catsItemList.filter { it.id == f })
```

Comment: Очень благодарен вам, спасибо!

Comment: @Романыч поставь галочку, это лучше чем спасибо)

Comment: @Романыч Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: тут же таймер не дает___)))

Comment: Да, точно, сорян)